Oauth invalid token signature issue
We are developing an application but facing issues with oauth verification and I am not sure how to proceed on the same. The app is developed using flutter and the backend is developed using Node.js. The flutter code is something like this:
{
            "commentid": 1,
            "text": "Awesome photo!",
            "userid": "666414da008a0fc1d6ec3ef1",
            "username": "expandingplayboy2202",
            "cheers": 3,
            "createdat": "2024-06-16T20:52:03.229Z",
            "boos": 0,
            "award_type": [
                "Park bench",
                "Sunflower"
            ],
            "user_picture": null,
            "user_username": null
        },

and the backend code:
exports.googleAuth = async (req, res) => {


try {
    const { token } = req.body;
    const client = new OAuth2Client();
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token,
      requiredAudience: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    });
    const payload = ticket.getPayload();

if (!payload) {
  errorLogger.error("Invalid token provided for Oauth");
  res.status(400).json({
    message: "invalid token",
  });
}

const { email, email_verified, given_name, family_name } = payload;

if (!email_verified) {
  errorLogger.error("Email is not verified");
  res.status(400).json({
    message: "Email is not verified",
  });
}
let username = generateUsername() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
while (await User.findOne({ username })) {
  username = generateUsername() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
}
try {
  const picture = `https://api.multiavatar.com/${username}.png?apikey=${AVATAR_KEY}`;
  const user = await User.create({
    username: username,
    password: password,
    email: email.toLowerCase(),
    picture: picture,
    auth_type: "email",
  });
  activityLogger.info("User logged in successfully");
  sendToken(user, 200, res);
} catch (error) {
  errorLogger.error("Error in Oauth:", err);
  res.status(500).json({
    message: err,
  });
}


} catch (err) {
    errorLogger.error("Error in Oauth:", err);
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Error in Oauth",
    });
  }
};

Now I have verified it multiple times and the client id in the backend is same as aud of the token created by Flutter app.
The token is created by web app client ID and have also done the configuration for app using the documentation from Google. What am I missing here?

token is missing in your flutter code .
you have written const {token} = req.body  make sure to pass token from frontend to backend
